# Nginx server multiple S3 site on port 80

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3, nginx-config

I want to serve s3 files through nginx. Single subdomain works perfectly with following `/etc/nginx/conf.d/dev.conf`

```
server {
    listen         80;
    listen         [::]:80;
    server_name    dev.domain.net;

    location / {
         proxy_set_header Host 'dev.domain.net.s3.amazonaws.com';
         proxy_set_header Authorization '';
         proxy_hide_header x-amz-id-2;
         proxy_hide_header x-amz-request-id;
         proxy_hide_header Set-Cookie;
         proxy_ignore_headers "Set-Cookie";
         proxy_intercept_errors on;
         proxy_pass http://dev.domain.net.s3.amazonaws.com/;
         log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

Also want second subdomain `qa.domain.net` to work from the same Nginx instance, so added `/etc/nginx/conf.d/qa.conf`

```
server {
    listen         80;
    listen         [::]:80;
    server_name    qa.domain.net;

    location / {
         proxy_set_header Host 'qa.domain.net.s3.amazonaws.com';
         proxy_set_header Authorization '';
         proxy_hide_header x-amz-id-2;
         proxy_hide_header x-amz-request-id;
         proxy_hide_header Set-Cookie;
         proxy_ignore_headers "Set-Cookie";
         proxy_intercept_errors on;
         proxy_pass http://qa.domain.net.s3.amazonaws.com/;
         log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

But when I try to access `qa.domain.net`, I get `dev.domain.net`. What do I need to do here ?

Comment: Assuming doing `nginx -t ` shows no issues and you did a `reload` or `restart`

Comment: Yes, config is correct and reloaded/restarted.